# Are there any benchmarks for chatbot memory capabilities?

Tags: llm

Are there any benchmarks for chatbot memory capabilities?

For instance, [memGPT](https://github.com/cpacker/MemGPT) uses an ‘LLM judge’ which is instructed to evaluate whether or not the generated response is consistent with the gold response, using the chat dataset of https://parl.ai/projects/msc/.

Answer (score 2):

Benchmarks (not specific to chatbot):

- [Long Range Arena: A Benchmark for Efficient Transformers](https://arxiv.org/abs/2011.04006) ([GitHub repo](https://github.com/google-research/long-range-arena)).
- [LLM context utilization benchmark](https://github.com/stunningpixels/lou-eval).
- [Needle In A Haystack - Pressure Testing LLMs](https://github.com/gkamradt/LLMTest_NeedleInAHaystack/blob/main/README.md) (a similar task was used to assess Gemini 1.5, as mentioned in the report [Gemini 1.5: Unlocking multimodal understanding across millions of tokens of context](https://storage.googleapis.com/deepmind-media/gemini/gemini_v1_5_report.pdf) by Google DeepMind)

And a very interesting paper:

- Liu, Nelson F., Kevin Lin, John Hewitt, Ashwin Paranjape, Michele Bevilacqua, Fabio Petroni, and Percy Liang. "[Lost in the middle: How language models use long contexts.](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2307.03172.pdf)". TACL 2023.

---

Example of output from https://twitter.com/swyx/status/1722441535235768372:

[image]

[image]